# Is voting to reopen closed question which is posted by myself correct?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reopen-closed

Just noticed that i can vote for reopening closed question which is asked by myself.

So - there are actually only 4 votes necessary to reopen question.

Seems to me that it's like upvoting my own question.

Is this correct and shouldn't be changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with voting to reopen your own question.  It's probably a good idea to take an objective look at the question in light of the reason that it was closed, then try to edit the question to make it better fit community standards before voting to reopen.

Comment: Yeah... I didn't think about that in this light. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's correct. You can even vote to close your own question if you so wish.

So as long as you have enough rep you should be able to vote to close and reopen any question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also vote for yourself in elections, at least here in the USA. It's normal...

Comment: Makes sense. :)